# applicationContext could path could not be resolved

Tags: spring

i am getting this error, when i define the the applicationContext inside my spring simple database connection code.

but when i place the applicationContext where the java (DatabaseTestConnection.java) resides, it connects without any issues.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from class path resource
>   [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

### Source

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

<!--bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
p:url="${jdbc.url}"
p:username="${jdbc.username}"
p:password="${jdbc.password}" /-->

<bean id="databaseTestConnection" class="DatabaseTestConnection">
<property name="dataSource" ref="externalDataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="externalDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" scope="singleton"     destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClassName" value="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:odbc:;DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=C://Users//gopc//Documents//odbc_sql.accdb"/>
<property name="username" value=""/>
<property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->

</beans>
```

**DatabaseTestConnection.java**

```
import java.util.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class DatabaseTestConnection {

private JdbcTemplate jt;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jt = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    XmlBeanFactory bf = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml"));
    DatabaseTestConnection bn = (DatabaseTestConnection) bf.getBean("databaseTestConnection");
    int count = bn.jt.queryForInt("select count(*) from log_entry");
    System.out.println("cgk count:" + count);

    List <Map <String,Object> > ob = bn.jt.queryForList("select * from log_entry", args);
    System.out.println("cgk size:" + ob.size());
    for (Map<String,Object> entry: ob )
    {
        System.out.println("ID:" + entry.get("ID"));
        System.out.println("DateCol:" + entry.get("DateCol"));
        System.out.println("Completed:" + entry.get("Completed"));
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Where is your `applicationContext.xml` is located? inside `WEB-INF` or is it a `classpath resource`?

Comment: it is located inside the WEB-INF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway you are just testing in local so,you can do this to load from context path

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("C:\\workspace\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\applicationContext.xml"); // in your case path to your applicationContext.xml file in your local.
```

Answer (score -1):

The `applicationContext.xml` file should be located inside the `WEB-INF/classes` folder.

Your configuration says the `applicationContext.xml` file is in the `classpath`. The classpath references to `WEB-INF/classes` directory in an servlet application.

Comment: how come when i place inside the src/java/ where the java program is located,  it is working fine..

Comment: If you place the file in `src/java` and compile the project then the file will get copied to the `classpath`.